# Bit banging with dd?

Tags: shell, pipe, dd

I need to change one byte at a well-known position of a binary file to a specific value, and am looking for a way to achieve that using command line tools.

Constraints:

- I need to change one single byte.
- I know the position of the byte in the file.
- I know what value I want in the byte. This may be anything, including non-printable characters in the 0x01–0x19 range.
- The new value does not depend on the old value, hence no need to retrieve the old value.

To zero out the 9th byte in a file, I would do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/the/file bs=1 seek=8 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

If I want anything other than zero in that file, I would try piping something containing the exact bit value into `dd`. Something like:

```
spit-out-bytes | dd of=/the/file bs=1 seek=8 count=1 conv=notrunc
```

What would I use for `spit-out-bytes`?

Comment: You probably need `conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your example is wrong, it would overwrite the first byte instead of the 9th (you want `seek` output, not `skip` input). It would also truncate the file to 1 byte, if it's a regular file instead of a block device (use `conv=notrunc` to avoid).

```
dd bs=1 seek=8 count=1 conv=notrunc if=/dev/zero of=somefile
```

Triple check each dd command before you run it...

> What would I use for `spit-out-bytes`?

You can try echo or printf...

```
$ echo -n -e '\x00\x88\xaa\xff' | hexdump -C
00000000  00 88 aa ff                                       |....|
00000004

$ printf '\x00\x88\xaa\xff' | hexdump -C
00000000  00 88 aa ff                                       |....|
00000004
```

On a sidenote, technically if you're sure your source will be only 1 byte large, you can skip the `count=1` in the dd command. However, I prefer to leave it in as a stopgap measure just in case. It's easy to have surplus bytes in the output (e.g. `echo` would normally append a newline character).

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake! I’ve fixed it.